# How to match 2 arrays, and loop through to display an array value?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to match two arrays, if matched then loop through array value to display them on the page.

This is how I am doing it.

```
$productIDs = array(
    '0' => array(
        'product_id' => '565355',
        'product_name' => 'stackPDF',
        'product_file' => 'http://www.example.com/stack.pdf',
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'product_id' => '563423',
        'product_name' => 'lostPDF',
        'product_file' => 'http://www.example.com/lost.pdf',
    ),
    '3' => array(
        'product_id' => '4442',
        'product_name' => 'No product',
        'product_file' => '',
    )
);

function getProducts($productIDs){

    $getIDs  = explode(',', $_GET['product_id']);

    $intersection = array();
    foreach($productIDs as $items)
    {
        $intersection[] = array_intersect($items, $getIDs);
    }

    if(!empty($intersection)){
        return $intersection;
    } else {
        echo "There are no products available!";
    }
}
$getProducts = getProducts($productIDs);

function getDownloads($getProducts){

    foreach($getProducts as $item){
        print_r($item);
    }

}
$getDownloads = getDownloads($getProducts);
```

In the getProducts() function, I'm checking to see if the `product_id` in the header match any of the `product_id` in $productIDs, to only show the available links for those that are in the header.

$getProducts variable has the available `product_id` that's already matched in an array, and in the $getDownloads I was trying to "If id's are available, loop through and display the `product_file` parameter value from the multidimensional array" but I can't seem to loop through it, rather I can't figure out how to match it/return the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
array_filter($array, function($v) use($id){ return $v['product_id'] == $id;})
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is:

```
$item_exists =  array_filter($productIDs, function($item) use ($check) {
    return md5(json_encode($item)) == md5(json_encode($check));
});
```

`json_encode` will serialize the array to string and `md5` will create a compare key, if they are equal, it will be inserted in the `$item_exists` array.

**Edit:** I was thinking of comparing product objects, but I guess you need the ID's only, you can use something like this:

```
$existing_values = array_filter($productIDs, function($p)use($getIDs){
     return in_array($p["product_id"], $getIDs); 
});
```

Comment: It keeps returning "Array", that's it.

Comment: you need to `print_r` or `var_dump` the existing values array.

Comment: I used print_r, first thing I tried, just "Array". var_dump just returns "array(0) { } "

Comment: `print_r` won't return Array. Maybe that's the output of something else?